# Связи между таблицами

Tags: sql

В БД имеется:
Таблица календарь:
(День,Месяц,Год)
Таблица Статус:(работает,в отпуске,выходной)

Таблица Сотрудник:
(Имя,фамилия,сколько лет)

Как правильно составить таблицу календарь,чтобы допустим 2 сотрудника ссылаются на один и тот же день,но у одного он рабочий,у другого - выходной. У меня получается так что в таблице Календарь 2 строки одного и того же дня но с разным статусом. Т.е. если у нас 3 статуса,3 сотрудника и один день-у нас таблица Календарь забивается уже 9 строками,что очень много,есть другие,более правильные варианты ?

Comment: Тут важно понять что для вас означает одна строка в таблице `Календарь`, если вы хотите чтобы она была одна на день.

Comment: @t0lik мне просто кажется саму таблицу календарь можно фиксировано заполнить на 31 день и не трогать,ведь она одинакова для всех работников,а статус работы узнать в определенный день можно ,создав вспомогательную таблицу,это пока догадки,не верю,что нет более красивого пути...

Comment: @Anastasia у меня примерно так сейчас,я вот тоже думаю что этот вариант не очень...

Comment: Тогда Вам сначала необходимо определиться какие данные в (выборке) запросе  вы хотите увидеть...Таблицу Календарь со всеми датами, статусами и сотрудниками рекомендую оставить, так как если вам понадобится сделать запрос по сотруднику - в какие дни он работал, а в какие отдыхал - единая база будет кстати... Давайте определимся, что вы хотите увидеть в конце: 
1. Выборка со статусами сотрудников (запрос из таблицы Календарь)
2. Выборка по сотрудникам (запрос из таблицы Календарь)
3. Выборка по дате - день, месяц, год (запрос из таблицы Календарь)

Comment: Язык запросов SQL как раз и предполагает, что вы из нескольких таблиц формируете новую таблицу (запрос), с необходимыми данными. То есть любая новая таблица это запрос, между основными таблицами строятся связи.

Comment: @Anastasia в идеале мне нужно получить статус работника по дате

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как получить статус работника по дате?
Вам необходимо **построить запрос на основе трех таблиц**.

**Таблица 1. Сотрудники:**

Столбцы: ID - идентификатор (обязательный ключ), ФИО - ФИО сотрудника.

**Таблица 2. Статус:**

Столбцы: ID - идентификатор (обязательный ключ), Статус - Статус сотрудника.

**Таблица 3. Календарь:**

Столбцы: ID - идентификатор (обязательный ключ), Дата, ФИО (из таблицы 1), Статус (из таблицы 2).

**Запрос:**

Дата (из таблицы 3), Статус (из таблицы 3), ФИО (из таблицы 3).

По-другому никак. Общая таблица из которой берутся данные для запроса - должна быть. Из Таблицы Календарь в запросе будут выведены только выбранные вами данные - по Дате, Статусу и ФИО сотрудника (по всем трем столбцам).

Соответственно, если вы хотите получить данные по статусу, то нужно создать несколько запросов. Если нужно вывести по трем статусам, значит должно быть три запроса с разным значением статуса. Если по дате - значит в запросе необходимо указать значение даты.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю,что в итоге таблица календарь будет хранить буквально каждый день вплоть до месяца-года и по другому никак?
т.е. у меня 31 строка уходит под 1 сотрудника

Comment: Не обязательно. Это основная база, из которой вы выбираете необходимые вам данные (создаете запрос). Вы можете разделить таблицы по месяцам и по годам, если не хотите хранить много данных в одной таблице, тогда все равно нужно строить запрос уже из нескольких таблиц, а не из одной.

Comment: Допустим у вас база данных 2019 год, в ней таблицы с месяцами - Май, Июнь, Июль. Вы можете объединить данные из таблицы Май и Июнь, но сможете ли объединить данные из двух баз 2019 и 2020 год - это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Давайте разберемся сколько у вас сотрудников и посчитаем сколько строк на один месяц... Если действительно много и удобнее работать с меньшим количеством данных, то можно разделить и по месяцам. Но если нужно объединять две разные базы данных, то это зависит от СУБД.

Comment: Да я посчитаю,тут не проблема,просто хотел уточнить формат хранения дней,спасибо вам

Comment: Повторюсь, вдруг не увидели изменения - если действительно много и удобнее работать с меньшим количеством данных, то можно разделить таблицы по месяцам и базы данных по годам. Но если нужно объединять две разные базы данных, то это зависит от СУБД.

Comment: Еще все зависит от обработки данных, как обработка данных пойдет быстрее? Когда запрос сделан из 12-ти таблиц или когда запрос сделан из одной? Когда в таблице 1000 строк или когда в каждой отдельной таблице по 200 строк? Это все надо учитывать и тестировать. А так, базы данных способны хранить большие массивы данных, другой вопрос сколько хотите обработать - 600 тысяч или всего лишь каких-то 6 тысяч.

Comment: получится в итоге около 7000 строк для 1 года,просто я изначально хотел узнать возможно ли избежать однотипного insert 
1 ivanov ivan 11.01.2020 work
2 ivanov ivan 12.01.2020 work
3 ivanov ivan 13.01.2020 work

Comment: про какой запрос речь?

Comment: "insert 1 ivanov ivan 11.01.2020 work 2 ivanov ivan 12.01.2020 work 3 ivanov ivan 13.01.2020 work" - не поняла что это... Здесь вы передаете значения, а вы же говорили что вам их нужно получить из таблицы

Comment: ну я их еще и вставляю,я про инсерты и говорил про 7000 строк

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю что вы хотите составить табель дежурства. да так что в одно и тоже время работал один сотрудник остальные были либо в отпуске на больничном либо на выходном. 
Задача составить на будущее таблицу это к динамическому программированию. Если Вам известно кто и когда работал/отдыхал то это вопрос составления запроса.

Таблица календарь будет иметь различные варианты для каждого сотрудника.

Календарь дней сотрудника 1 ....

Объединят в одну нужно по какому либо статусу.

Календарь рабочих дней сотрудников ....
Календарь выходных дней сотрудников ....
Календарь отпускных дней сотрудников ....

если вздумаете объединить то у Вас получится как в Вашем примере 3х3

Comment: график заранее известен,тут больше вопрос к эффективности заполнения этой самой таблицы:на данный момент для 4 сотрудников один день выглядит вот так
`1 october 2020 выходной`
`1 october 2020 отпуск`
`1 october 2020 уволен`
`1 october 2020 работает`
а дальше надо будет месяц-год,видимо по другому-никак